# Can Disk Utility and Disk Warrior be used on a Fusion volume containing Mac OS X

Tags: disk-utility, vmware, osx-server, filesystem

I have Snow Leopard Server 10.6.8 running in a VMware Fusion 4.1.3 virtual machine.  When I run a Disk Utility "Verify Disk" from within the VM, errors are reported.

> Invalid B-tree node size
>
> The volume   could not be verified completely.
>
> Error: This disk needs to be repaired. Start up your
> computer with another disk (such as your Mac OS X installation disc),
> and then use Disk Utility to repair this disk.

I have successfully mounted the .vmdk volume using VMDKMounter.app (from Fusion 3) after installing Fuse for OS X 2.4.2.

The problem is that both Disk Utility & Disk Warrior want to unmount the volume before making repairs.  Both apps then produce error dialogs.

Is there a way of running these utilities on a Fusion volume?

Answer (score 1):

Both Disk Warrior and Disk Utility will work on a .vmdk mounted volume using the VMDKMounter.app **IF** the .vmdk is not damaged.

I created a new .vmdk, recopied the drive image and both Disk Warrior 4.4 and Disk Utility worked fine.

It appears that if the .vmdk becomes damaged somehow, the normal tools I use will not work.

Keeping good backups appears to be even more important when you add Virtual Machines to the mix.